# How to convert seconds into hours in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have (Seconds)column of numbers which are integers

Eg.

### Seconds

345
456
234
456
678
3456

How to convert it into hours, which must be in in **HH:MM** format?

Comment: With `s` being the number of seconds, `s / 3600` is the number of hours. `(s / 60) mod 60` is the number of minutes. (And `s mod 60` is the remaining number of seconds)

Comment: @Ronald  if the seconds is "6519178", and if I apply the above logic, I'm getting 1810:52 as answer  Query: concat(concat(sum(6519178)/3600,':'),(sum(6519178)/60)%60)

Comment: Make sure to do an integer division. Then 6519178 / 3600 = 1810, (6519178 / 60) % 60 =  52 and last but not least 6519178 % 60 = 58. 1810 * 3600 + 52 * 60 + 58 = 6516000 + 3120 + 58 = 6519178.